# How to get a list of booleans where the true values follow a bernoulie distribution

Tags: haskell, random

Currently I have some haskell code that requires a random list Boolean values. Currently I am following the approach in the book (Learn you a haskell) which is

```
list = randoms someStdGen :: [Bool]
```

However this is no good for me as the previous list will have about the same number of Falses and Trues.

What is the best way to get a list so that, for example, only about 1/4 of the elements are True.

Comment: Everybody thinks the same thing reading that book... *"How do i a get a true random seed..?"* You simply can't inside pure logic. That's the reason why you are expected to do all your random thingies by `randomIO :: System.Random.Random a => IO a` inside the `IO` monad.

Comment: @Redu. How would e get the list using System.Random.Random then. I do not have a problem working inside the IO monad

Comment: @Redu OP did not ask for this, this is a perfectly viable question and makes sense in a pure context, given that OP already uses a `RandomGen g`.

Comment: @Redu it can actually make a lot of sense to extract a random seed as a hash of the arguments of a pure function. This way you still get essentially random behaviour across inputs, but anyway the compiler is happy because you stay referentially transparent and, more importantly, retain all the benefits of referential transparency.

Comment: Minor note: for the specific case of 1/4 probability, you could use `list2 = go list where go (x:y:zs) = x&&y : go zs` since the AND of two uniformly distributed bits gives what you want. This does not generalize too well, though.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by generating a list of `Float`s and comparing them to your `p` value. If the float is below `p` return `True` otherwise `False`, e.g.

```
bernoulli :: RandomGen g => Float -> g -> [Bool]
bernoulli p = map (<p) . randoms
```

You can use this like this:

```
> gen <- newStdGen
> take 10 $ bernoulli 0.4 gen
[False,False,False,False,False,True,True,False,True,True]
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside `IO` monad you approach might look like

```
rlist :: Int -> IO [Bool]
rlist x = mapM (fmap (<x)) $ replicate 10 $ randomRIO (0,9)

λ> rlist 4
[True,True,False,True,False,True,False,False,True,True]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function, say *makeBernoulliSeq*, that takes the probability and a trial count, and gives you a monadic action returning a list of boolean values.

That way, it is easy to combine this with other computations requiring random numbers.

Sample code:

```
{-#  LANGUAGE  ScopedTypeVariables  #-}

import  System.Random
import  Control.Monad.Random

makeBernoulliSeq :: MonadRandom mr => Double -> Int -> mr [Bool]
makeBernoulliSeq proba count =
    let  act1 = getRandom  -- get one value between 0.0 and 1.0
         actN = sequence (replicate count act1)
    in  do
            xs :: [Double] <- actN -- "count" values inside [0.0 --> 1.0)
            return  $  map  (proba >)  xs


main = do
    let count = 10000               -- number of trials
        proba = 0.25                -- probability of success

        randomSeed = 424344         -- ideally passed from command line argument
        gen0 = mkStdGen randomSeed  -- for reproducibility of random numbers

        (bList, gen1) = runRand  (makeBernoulliSeq proba count)  gen0

        -- How many True values did we get ?
        successCount = length $ filter id bList
        expected     = floor $ proba * (fromIntegral count)

    putStrLn $ (show successCount) ++ " successes out of " ++
                   (show expected) ++ " expected"
```

### Program output:

```
2468 successes out of 2500 expected
```

**Note:** I generally avoid calling [*getRandoms*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.5.1.2/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Class.html#v:getRandoms) or similar functions that return an unlimited supply of random values. This is because they involve a call to *split* the random number generator, and it seems to me that the [standard code for *split*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/src/System.Random.html#stdSplit) is a bit fishy. For the standard generator, the first value returned by `getRandoms` differs from the single value returned by `getRandom`.